# Drivers for Quick Cam pro 9000 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-webcam

I have a Logitech Quick Cam Pro 9000 that I want to install on my Windows 7 installation. The user manual specifies that I have to install the software before I install the camera. But my experience is that software from hardware vendors tend to decrease computer performance, so I was wondering if this camera will work by only plugging it in and letting Windows 7 find and install the drivers for it.

I could've just tried installing it of course, but again, hardware vendors are notorious for screwing up things, and I wouldn't want to make it impossible to install the camera by doing things in the wrong order, hence the question - I assume somebody is more knowledgeable than me on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no problems after just plugging that same model in and ignoring the disc completely (Windows 7 64-bit). But it does seem to install much the same stuff as on the disk (albeit a newer version) which includes the usual entry added to startup, and if I remember rightly a Driver Update utility in Control Panel plus a service.

Answer (score 1):

just do this; Go to Device Manager  -> Properties -> Update drivers.  :)